# Mat-icon-button is not clickable if input tag is inside button at Angular Material 15

Tags: html, angular, angular-material-15

I have button into my actions list, and by some reason after migrating from Angular Material 14 to 15 version, when I click this button doing nothing.

```
    <li>   
      <button [attr.station-action]="'upload-file'" color="primary"
                 mat-icon-button
                 [disabled]="!estimateStation.canUpload">
         <input [disabled]="!estimateStation.canUpload" title="" id="upload-input-{{stationIndex}}" type="file" 
              (change)="onFileSelected($event, estimateStation, estimate)">
         <span class="icon-upload"></span>
   </button>
</li>
```

If I changing mat-icon-button for example to mat-raised-button, it works fine and window for file choosing is opening. How to fix it? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Adding for input style="z-index: 1;" fixed the problem

Comment: are you using anydesk or teamviewr so i wil take it and resolved it